# Jquery fadeTo on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, fadeto

I am using a plugin called anything slider and am trying to make the controls fade after 4 seconds (which is working) then change opacity back to 1 on mouseover (not working). Here is what I have so far...what am I doing wrong?

```
$(slider.$controls).mouseover(function() 
slider.$controls.fadeTo(400, 1.0);
});

$(function () {
    var fadeTime = 400,
        fadeDelay = 4000,
        timer, hideControls = function (slider) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            setTimeout(function () {
                slider.$controls.fadeTo(fadeTime, 0.3);
                $('.tooltip').fadeOut(fadeTime);
            }, fadeDelay);
        };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you sould replace every `slider.$controls.fadeTo` with `slider.controls.fadeTo`

```
$(slider.controls).mouseover(function() 

    $(this).fadeTo(400, 1.0);

});
```

Comment: `slider.$controls` is valid, is there a reason to change it?

Comment: I know its valid from syntax point of view but the code should be consistent; either make all of them slider.$controls or slider.controls

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on line 2. Where you have

```
slider.$controls.fadeTo...
```

you should have

```
$(this).fadeTo...
```

because once you've entered the anonymous function on line 1, the `this` object now refers to the DOM element upon which you're executing this code, which is the element represented by `slider.controls`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>First you use `slider.controls` to target the control element(s), then you use `slider.$controls` to target the same element(s). I think you need to decide which one it is.</s>

Also, inside a callback function you can use `this` as a reference to the element that has had the event fired on it:

```
$(slider.controls).bind('mouseover', function () {
    $(this)...
});
```

<s>Otherwise if you want to fade-in-out all the controls at the same time then you just need to figure out if you need to use `slider.$controls` or `slider.controls`.</s>

**UPDATE**

I see you have changed your question and now you are using `slider.$controls` both times. You should put your `mouseover` code inside the `document.ready` event handler so you know the DOM elements are available:

```
$(function () {

    slider.$controls.mouseover(function() 
        slider.$controls.fadeTo(400, 1.0);
    });

    var fadeTime = 400,
        fadeDelay = 4000,
        timer, hideControls = function (slider) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            setTimeout(function () {
                slider.$controls.fadeTo(fadeTime, 0.3);
                $('.tooltip').fadeOut(fadeTime);
            }, fadeDelay);
        };
```

Also I noticed that you wrapped `slider.$controls` in a jQuery object the first time, but not the second, make sure to do that if `slider.$controls` is not already a jQuery object (many times developers put a `$` as the first character of a variable name to denote that it is a jQuery object).

Comment: the second function that fades it to opacity 0.3 works perfectly. I still cant get the mouseover to work...

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?